# Sharepoint 2010 is not listing all users from the Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have set up a SharePoint 2010 Standard server in a farm configuration with an AD as the backend for authentication. This so far has been working great but I have been noticing quite a few users are not showing up when I search for them.

Note: This is a large 75,000+ user active directory

What do I need to do to get these communicating again or communicating properly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using any LDAP strings to filter the users?
Have you checked your import logs?  If you keep seeing the same number of users getting imported, but your pool of users in AD is not staying the same size, then it could be some kind of limit, or timeout when doing the import.

Answer (score 1):

A few points worth checking...

Do they appear in the User Profile Sync service? If you open Central Administration and go to the User Profile Service, you can view the imported user profiles from the Manage User Profiles page.

It may also be worth checking if you are importing users from only certain containers in AD, this can also be checked from the User Profile Service > Configure Synchronisation Connections.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is simplistic, but without further details, this is the best I can offer:

First you do need to create the users' accounts in sharepoint (import them, basically) - they will not be imported into sharepoint by default as users of the system.

Second, you might look at using the profiles feature to import information about users on a regular basis - not sure if that's a standard or enterprise-only feature.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit, What I mean is they are not showing up when I search with the people finder to add them as a SharePoint user.